# AngularJS orderBy filter not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show an array (`$scope.stored_questions_clusters`) sorted in descending order by the position of each element, the problem is that I don't get the desired result.

In this example I do a `ng-repeat = "question cluster stored in clusters questions | orderBy '- question_cluster.position'"`, at each iteration I create a panel with bootstrap where I print the position, so what I would expect is a list sorted by their position, but I don't get this...

Here is the code I use:

```
<div style="margin-top:30px;" ng-show="mostrarPreguntas==true">
  <div ng-repeat="question_cluster in stored_questions_clusters |  orderBy:'-question_cluster.position'" class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-11">
            <h3>{{question_cluster.position}}.- {{question_cluster.title}}</h3>
              </div>
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

And this is the result:

[image: sort_by_error]

This is the console.log of each element:

[image]

Comment: Is `question_cluster.position` a `number` or a `string`?

Comment: It should be an integer... I guess... It's the first time I'm working with AngularJS and responses in JSON... is there a way to check it?

Comment: I mean if there is a method like in Rails where you use .class, anyway, it's an integer, I put the console log of each element in the post.

Comment: I'm 90% sure you want `orderBy: '- position'`, not `'- question_cluster.position'`

Comment: Thanks! it worked (I'm pretty new with Angular)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ng-repeat="question_cluster in stored_questions_clusters |  orderBy:'-position'"`

This will sort your `question_clusters` in descending order

Have a look at the first example on [Angulars order by documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)